# Populate Django database(SQL)

Tags: python, sql, django

I am learning Django, a little difficult for me, so i have some problem with Fields M2M, OTO, FK and i'm stuck, I'm trying to fill in the database(SQL), everything seems to work, but there is an intermediate field

```
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

**book_authors** this table is empty, read the documentation, didn't help :p

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    
    
    class Author(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        age = models.IntegerField()
    
    
    class Publisher(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    
    
    class Book(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        pages = models.IntegerField()
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
        rating = models.FloatField()
        authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
        publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        pubdate = models.DateField('date published')
    
    
    class Store(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

admin.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from annotate_aggregate.models import Author, Publisher, Store, Book
    
    admin.site.register(Author)
    admin.site.register(Publisher)
    admin.site.register(Book)
    admin.site.register(Store)
```

management/commands/seed.py

```
import random
from django.utils import timezone
from annotate_aggregate.models import Author, Book, Store, Publisher
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('arg', type=int)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        num = options['arg']

        for _ in range(int(num)):
            Author.objects.create(name=fake.name(), 
    age=random.randint(20, 70))

        for _ in range(int(num)):
            Publisher.objects.create(name=fake.company())

            for publisher in Publisher.objects.all():
                for _ in range(int(num)):
                    books = [Book(
                        name=fake.sentence(),
                        price=random.uniform(29.99, 225.9),
                        pages=random.randint(50, 300),
                        rating=round(random.uniform(1, 5), 2),
                        pubdate=timezone.now(),
                        publisher=publisher)]
                    Book.objects.bulk_create(books)
        books = Book.objects.all()
        for _ in range(int(num)):
            store = Store.objects.create(name=fake.company())
            store.books.set(books)
            store.save()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfjwT.png)

Comment: you never add an author to the Book you appended to publisher. Loop through the books and add a random author to each.

Comment: @AMG yes, i'm understand that, but i don't know, how it's fix in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the books you've created and add an author to each.

Something like the following loops over all your books, and adds a single random author to each. Uses `random.choice` on your list of authors you have already created in the `authors = [Author(name=fake.name(), age=random.randint(20, 70)) for _ in range(1, 6)]` line. I didn't test this, but I think it should be close.

```
import random

for book in Book.objects.all():
    book.authors.add(random.choice(authors))
```